# Uncaught TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function error in browser console

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload an image to Amaazon s3 bucket through react using the below code.
I am getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function" in browser console.
Could anyone please help on this.
I am calling this upload function from another component, anyways the page is loading , after selecting the file its throwing the above mentioned error.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
import awsconfig from './aws-exports';
import {AmplifySignOut, withAuthenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react'
import ReactS3 from 'react-s3';
const file = require('fs')
const AWS = require ("aws-sdk")
const key_ID = "**********" //IAM key id
const SECRET_KEY = "************************"
const Bucket_name = "mediabucket321";
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
     accessKeyId: key_ID,
     secretAccessKey: SECRET_KEY, 
});



Amplify.configure(awsconfig)

class upload extends Component {

    upload(e){
        const filename=e.target.files[0].name;
        console.log(filename);
        console.log("before upload");
    console.log(file);
        const fileContent = file.readFileSync(filename);
const params = {
        Bucket: Bucket_name,
        Key: 'img1.jpg',
        Body: fileContent,
        ContentType: "jpg"
    }
        s3.upload(params,(err,data)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err)

        }
        else{
            console.log("File uploaded successfully",data.Location);
        }
    })
    }
  render() {
      return (
          <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', padding: 30 }}>
              <div><h2>Upload a movie here</h2>
                   <h2>Enter the file location and click upload</h2>
                <input type="text" name ="upload"/> <br/>
                <input type="file" onChange = {this.upload}/>
              </div>
          </div>
      );
  }
}

export default upload;
```

Comment: fs is a node api, it is not available in the browser.

Comment: Thank you Benjamin, but how would it be a problem because I wrote the code in node.js and running it in local host

Answer (score 1):

The *fs* library is not available in the browser, it is nodejs specific.

Comment: Thank you, but any suggestions for the alternative

Comment: If you are prompting a user to upload an image use a [file input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file).

Answer (score 0):

[`fs`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) is a Node.js only API, not available in the browser.

[v3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/) of the AWS SDK also provides better browser support, the [S3 component](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/index.html) can be sourced individually

```
yarn add @aws-sdk/client-s3
import { S3Client } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3"
```

You normally don't want to distribute the AWS credentials to browsers so can generate a [pre signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html) where you do house the AWS keys for the browser to use.

There are [react components available](https://github.com/odysseyscience/react-s3-uploader) that do this already in a secure manner.